# Flyway - Does it keep track of schema and object dependency

Tags: flyway

I have installed Flyway Software and trying to deploy code. I have a Scenario

1. I created a file V1_01_CREATE_TABLE.SQL to create a table.
2. Created a file  V1_01_CREATE_PACKAGE.SQL  - This package will hold code to insert a row into one of the columns in table created in step 1.
3. Created a file V1_01_02_ALTER_TABLE.SQL - This SQL will rename the column which was being referred in step2.

This will invalidate the package if I run 1, 2 & 3. How does FLYWAY handle such a situation? Does it understand object dependency?

Comment: https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/how explains how it works.

Comment: Thank you. But i couldn't find what i was looking for. i want to know if Flyway sorts the object dependency.

Comment: The above link makes it clear that Flyway tracks only migrations as a whole (where each script is a migration if you use that interface). There is no analysis of individual objects. All it does is execute the commands you give it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [explained in the manual](https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/how), **Flyway simply passes your SQL scripts** to the database to be executed, and records the success or failure of their execution.

Flyway has no interest or understanding of the content of your scripts. Flyway never looks at the content of those scripts. In that sense, there is no “intelligence” in Flyway.

Flyway is like the postal worker delivering your letters without opening the envelope. You are the author, and you take full responsibility for the logic and correctness of the SQL scripts. You are responsible for following the naming conventions so your scripts run in the correct order.

After initially creating its metadata table, Flyway makes very limited use of JDBC and SQL. Flyway does little more than make a connection to the database server, determine which of the scripts have yet to be run, and say to the database “Here, run this script, and this script, and then run this script.” while recording the success or failure of each run.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I feel like it's better this way. The smarter you try to make it, the further you get from the "do one thing and do it well" principle.

Answer (score 0):

You should name your scripts in order they needs to be executed

```
V1.0.0_CREATE_TABLE.SQL
V1.0.1_CREATE_PACKAGE.SQL
V1.0.2_ALTER_TABLE.SQL
```

This will execute scripts in migrated